Authorize script for file not user
PLATFORM: Google Sheets GIVEN: Input spreadsheet and Data spreadsheet
ISSUE: Script will not edit Data sheet because user is only authorized for Input sheet.
DESIRED OUTCOME: User can click button to run macro to edit Data sheet without being authorized to view or edit Data sheet.
I'm trying to google and search here, but I'm not sure how to find what I need. I keep getting simple 'authorize script' tutorials. I imagine this is something with Deploy or script authorization that I'm not used to.
I have a Data sheet with 60 columns and a user that should be able to see and edit 20 of those columns, but not all 60. I built an importrange to pull in some of the columns to view and a script (in the Input sheet) to send user inputs back to edit the data sheet (click-button). This works for me as I'm authorized in both sheets, but does not work for the end user as they are authorized only for the Input sheet. How can I authorize the script but not the user to do that editing?

answer relates to locked cells rather than unshared files so I'm leaving it here so someone might find it. I haven't tested the options yet, but it looks like the fix might work even though locked cells is something different.
